# How To Cast Eloquent Pivot Parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following Eloquent Models with relationships:

```
class Lead extends Model 
{
    public function contacts() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact')
                    ->withPivot('is_primary');
    }
}

class Contact extends Model 
{
    public function leads() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lead')
                    ->withPivot('is_primary');
    }
}
```

The pivot table contains an additional param (`is_primary`) that marks a relationship as the primary. Currently, I see returns like this when I query for a contact:

```
{
    "id": 565,
    "leads": [
        {
            "id": 349,
             "pivot": {
                "contact_id": "565",
                "lead_id": "349",
                "is_primary": "0"
             }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to cast the `is_primary` in that to a boolean? I've tried adding it to the `$casts` array of both models but that did not change anything.

Comment: Can you also share the code for how you are adding the `$casts` property?

Comment: @NomanUrRehman `$casts = ['is_primary'];` on either model. It works for properties actually on those tables.

Comment: Please update your question to include this information if my answer helps.

Comment: I have been trying to make my returned array look like yours, a nested array. I read about relationships and they seem to work. But it seems like calling Model::with returns a reference that has to be dereferenced. Could you please confirm or correct me!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since this is an attribute on the pivot table, using the `$casts` attribute won't work on either the `Lead` or `Contact` model.

One thing you can try, however, is to use a custom `Pivot` model with the `$casts` attribute defined. Documentation on custom pivot models is [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables). Basically, you create a new `Pivot` model with your customizations, and then update the `Lead` and the `Contact` models to use this custom `Pivot` model instead of the base one.

First, create your custom `Pivot` model which extends the base `Pivot` model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PrimaryPivot extends Pivot {
    protected $casts = ['is_primary' => 'boolean'];
}
```

Now, override the `newPivot()` method on the `Lead` and the `Contact` models:

```
class Lead extends Model {
    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        return new \App\PrimaryPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}

class Contact extends Model {
    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        return new \App\PrimaryPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked exactly as I had hoped. Slightly annoying that you need an additional class for it, but I can deal with that. Thanks! Just in case anyone reads this later, you need the pivot on the opposite table of what is being queried. So if you are querying Contact and attaching Leads, you need to have the `newPivot` override on `Lead` and the opposite if you are querying Leads and attaching Contacts.

Comment: Though this solution is correct and currently the best way of doing this, it really bothers me. Laravel is always so clean and having to create a new model just to cast extended pivot table attributes seems like incredible overkill.

Answer (score 55):

In **Laravel 5.4.14** this issue has been resolved. You are able to define a custom pivot model and tell your relationships to use this custom model when they are defined. See [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), under the heading *Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models*.

To do this you need to create a class to represent your pivot table and have it extend the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` class. On this class you may define your `$casts` property.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class CustomPivot extends Pivot
{
    protected $casts = [
        'is_primary' => 'boolean'
    ];
}
```

You can then use the `using` method on the `BelongsToMany` relationship to tell Laravel that you want your pivot to use the specified custom pivot model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lead extends Model
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact')->using('App\CustomPivot');
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you access your pivot by using `->pivot`, you should find that it is an instance of your custom pivot class and the `$casts` property should be honoured.

---

**Update 1st June 2017**

The issue raised in the comments by @cdwyer regarding updating the pivot table using the usual `sync`/`attach`/`save` methods is expected to be fixed in Laravel 5.5 which is due to be released next month (July 2017).

See Taylor's comment at the bottom of [this bug report](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18536) and his commit, fixing the issue [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19335).

Comment: This seems to be accurate for 5.4, but I can't find any documentation on how this interacts with `attach`/`sync` helper methods. In other words, it seems to work when _retrieving_ data via `->pivot`, but _setting/creating_ data is a different story. 

Attaching the intermediate model doesn't seem to "honor" the pivot $casts. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I had never checked that before. I have had a bit of a mess around with it this morning and can confirm that using the methods to update the related models and associated pivot attributes (e..g `attach`, `sync`, `updateExistingPivot` etc.) aren't working. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18536) on Github for this.

Comment: So what's the current work-around if you can't rely on `attach` or `sync`?

Comment: At the minute in my case I've created a model to represent the pivot table as the casts works fine with normal models. However, another workaround might be to do the casting manually until the issue is resolved. You should be able to achieve this by creating accessors and mutators on the pivot model.

Comment: @Jonathon accessors/mutators in the pivot model like the one you've demonstrated above? Does seem like the most elegant stop-gap solution. When you say you've created a model to represent the pivot table, are you referring to a standard Model or the above?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes I think that would probably be the best way to achieve it. I'm fairly sure Laravel checks for any custom accessors/mutators before attempting to cast so even after you update Laravel when the fix has been released it shouldn't break anything for you. In my scenario, I have created a standard Model (Not a pivot) to represent the pivot table and adjusted the my relationships to point at that intermediate model.

Comment: Taylor's merged commits, for reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19335

Thanks for your work on this, @Jonathan!

Comment: Perfect Well Solution.

Comment: This should be the top answer. I don't see any issues with attach or sync in Laravel 5.6, I think all of the issues described above were resolved, seems perfect, tested using array casts on json fields

Comment: This woked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Good news! Tylor already fixed this bug:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10533

In Laravel 5.1 or higher you can use dot notation for pivot casts:

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'integer',
    'courses.pivot.course_id' => 'integer',
    'courses.pivot.active' => 'boolean'
]
```

Comment: @molerat It worked at Laravel versions 5.2 or 5.3. I did not tried it on newer versions. I can make a research about this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by @patricus above is absolutely correct, however, if like me **you're looking to also benefit from casting out from JSON-encoded strings inside a pivot table** then read on.

### The Problem

I believe that there's a bug in Laravel at this stage. The problem is that when you instantiate a pivot model, it uses the native Illuminate-Model `setAttributes` method to "copy" the values of the pivot record table over to the pivot model.

This is fine for most attributes, but gets sticky when it sees the `$casts` array contains a JSON-style cast - it actually double-encodes the data.

### A Solution

The way I overcame this is as follows:

**1. Set up your own Pivot base class from which to extend your pivot subclasses** (more on this in a bit)

**2. In your new Pivot base class, redefine the `setAttribute` method, commenting out the lines that handle JSON-castable attributes**

```
class MyPivot extends Pivot {
  public function setAttribute($key, $value)
  {
    if ($this->hasSetMutator($key))
    {
      $method = 'set'.studly_case($key).'Attribute';

      return $this->{$method}($value);
    }
    elseif (in_array($key, $this->getDates()) && $value)
    {
      $value = $this->fromDateTime($value);
    }

    /*
    if ($this->isJsonCastable($key))
    {
      $value = json_encode($value);
    }
    */

    $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

This highlights the removal of the `isJsonCastable` method call, which will return `true` for any attributes you have casted as `json`, `array`, `object` or `collection` in your whizzy pivot subclasses.

**3. Create your pivot subclasses using some sort of useful naming convention** (I do `{PivotTable}Pivot` e.g. FeatureProductPivot)

**4. In your base model class, change/create your `newPivot` method override to something a little more useful**

Mine looks like this:

```
public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
{
  $class = 'App\Models\\' . studly_case($table) . 'Pivot';

  if ( class_exists( $class ) )
  {
    return new $class($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
  }
  else
  {
    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
  }
}
```

Then just make sure you Models extend from your base model and you create your pivot-table "models" to suit your naming convention and voilà you will have working JSON casts on pivot table columns on the way out of the DB!

**NB: This hasn't been thoroughly tested and may have problems saving back to the DB.**

Comment: If you only have one json-able column, just add a set-mutator for that column and directly assign the value. You'll bypass the cast in the regular `setAttribute` without having to interfere so drastically in the rest of the functionality. Your analysis of the issue helped me greatly, hence the **+1**

Comment: Even cleaner btw, is to just pre-`json_decode()` the data in your `newPilot()` function, and pass it as an object/array to the parent instead of a `string`. That way you don't break anything in the target Pivot model.

Comment: Thanks @Blizz. You could do that, but as you correctly suggest, that is probably only practical for a single case. So while 'simpler' it is less flexible. But pragmatism ftw :) glad I was able to help

Comment: The issue I have is that the fix is only required in when a new pivot is created. With changing `setAttributes`, if the resulting model is ever assigned a new json value, you won't be able to save it to the database. Which is why - for me - modifying `setAttributes` is always the very last solution, as it is used for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add some extra checks to have the save and load functions working properly in Laravel 5.

```
class BasePivot extends Pivot
{
    private $loading = false;

    public function __construct(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
    {
        $this->loading = true;
        parent::__construct($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
        $this->loading = false;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        // First we will check for the presence of a mutator for the set operation
        // which simply lets the developers tweak the attribute as it is set on
        // the model, such as "json_encoding" an listing of data for storage.
        if ($this->hasSetMutator($key)) {
            $method = 'set'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute';

            return $this->{$method}($value);
        }

        // If an attribute is listed as a "date", we'll convert it from a DateTime
        // instance into a form proper for storage on the database tables using
        // the connection grammar's date format. We will auto set the values.
        elseif ($value && (in_array($key, $this->getDates()) || $this->isDateCastable($key))) {
            $value = $this->fromDateTime($value);
        }

        /**
         * @bug
         * BUG, double casting
         */
        if (!$this->loading && $this->isJsonCastable($key) && ! is_null($value)) {
            $value = $this->asJson($value);
        }


        $this->attributes[$key] = $value;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to achieve this is to tag on `withCasts` on the pivot relationship function:

```
  public function teachers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class, 'section_teacher', 'section_id', 'teacher_id')
        ->withPivot(['id', 'role', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])
        ->withCasts([
            'role' => TeacherSectionRoleEnum::class,
        ]);
}
```