# How to change value of extra column pivot has integer to string in laravel

Tags: laravel, integer, pivot, pivot-table, laravel-8

This image for my pivot table:

[image: this is my pivot table]

and the code below has for relationship

```
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_team', 'team_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('post');
```

and in controller im use this code:

```
$usersTeam = Team::find($id)->users()->get();
return json_encode($usersTeam);
```

and pic below is response:

[image: this response]

Now, im want if post is **0** return in json: `"post": "leader"` and if **1** return `"post": "member"`

How should I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Cast Eloquent Pivot Parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226496/how-to-cast-eloquent-pivot-parameters)

Comment: no im want use accessor for post field.